# How to configure WSO2 identity server to support multi tenant mode?

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to evaluate WSO2 identity server. One of the key featues I need to evaluate is the multi tenant support. How can I configure WSO2 identity server to support multi tenant mode?

Itay

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout Identity Server 4.0.0 Milestone 2 from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/scratch/wso2is-4.0.0/m2/). Multitenancy feature is available by default. Goto Configure-->Multitenancy

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: Thanks Thilini. I am trying to add a new tenant but keep getting an exception related to a missing partition in my LDAP. Can you please add a link to the relevant information how it works?